# AEM- IOS app integration

Tags: aem

I have an IOS app which I need to integrate with AEM. Can anyone guide me, how to do it.All I can see with adobe documents is to use phonegap and build app using it.

Comment: Can you be more specific ? What type of integration ? Do you want to control app content from AEM ?

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 things you can do:

1. Build a native app the queries AEM server and gets content as needed. In this case you might want to expose certain rest services for your app to consume.
2. Build app using the AEM mobile library or phone gap - for this you will have to create an new mobile app in AEM that uses angular JS and phonegap enterprise to build your app. In this case AEM allows you to manage the content independently

https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud-Apps/aem-phonegap-starter-kit - this is a good starting point for it. Checkout the code and run the maven command. It will build a phonegap app for you that you can build by configuring PGE in the build configurations

3. You can use AEMMobile. Primarily targeted towards creating independent content like magazines and catalogues for your site. AEMMobile is a fresh take at Adobe's Digital Publishing Suite. Here it allows you to create a website without having to write any code. Everything happens on the AEMMobile portal